# Creating pivot table using sql Query like CROSSTAB in postgresSQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot, crosstab

Table looks below

[image: Id q1 q2 q3 q4 1 6 7 8 9 2 5 Null Null Null 3 7 8 Null Null]

and expected answer is:

[image]

I want to use pivot option in sql server to get output as above

Comment: I think you want to do the exact opposite of pivoting. Your operation would be called unpivoting.

Comment: Agree.How to get output as expected?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I wrote a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, Value
FROM 

(SELECT id, q1, q2, q3,q4 FROM TEMPLATE)  AS pq

UNPIVOT
 
(

  Value FOR quarters IN (q1, q2, q3,q4) 
  
)AS UP;
```